# PHPActiveRecord Encoding Issue

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, phpmyadmin, phpactiverecord

I'm using `PHPActiveRecord` for managing my database models, however i'm experiencing some encoding issues.

I'm using `PHPMyAdmin v3.3.10.4`, `MySQL client v5.0.51a` and `PHPActiveRecord v1.0`.
My connection collation and all my tables are defined with `utf8_general_ci` collation.

My `PHPActiveRecord` connections is created like this:

```
$cfg->set_connections(array(
   'development' => 'mysql://username:password@mydomain.com/database?charset=utf8'));
```

If I manually insert an entry with special characters (for example é, ã, ç) through `PhpMyAdmin`, there is no problem, however when I insert entries through `PHPActiveRecord`, I cannot visualize the special characters correctly when browsing a table through `PhpMyAdmin`.

If I list my table entries and show them through a `PHP` page request, I have to set `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8')`, but I can list all entries with special characters correctly.

Is there any configuration I have to make on my database or `PhpMyAdmin` for listing entries with special characters created with `PHPActiveRecord` correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Version 1.0 of PHP ActiveRecord that you are using does not have support for specifying an encoding via "?charset=utf8". It was added later in v1.1, see [this commit](https://github.com/jpfuentes2/php-activerecord/commit/2f04229285433b3ef84c8160b390f7c8b135fd8b).

To verify that, check your copy of php-activerecord/lib/adapters/MysqlAdapter.php and search for "set_encoding". If you cannot find set_encoding function definition, it means you're using old version of PHP ActiveRecord that does not support "?charset=utf8" config parameter.

There are at least 2 ways to solve it:

A) Upgrade to latest nightly build of PHP ActiveRecord. There is a possibility upgrade will break your existing code, so test everything thoroughly with the new version of the library, OR

B) Simply add this code after you configured a connection:

```
YourModel::query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

It will set MySQL connection associated with that model to use UTF-8 character set. If you are using multiple MySQL connections (e.g. connecting to multiple databases), execute that query for each connection.